# Is it possible to create a canvas to extract image data without actually rendering the canvas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, chart.js

So, I have an application in Angular that uses Chart.js to generate some dynamic charts in some of the views of the application.
The application also has an ability to export some of the data to a PDF format via the PDFMake Javascript library which is rather basic but allows for basic text and image output to the PDF file.

The question is - can I, dynamically inside the factory in which I generate the data that'll be parsed by the PDFMake library, do the following:

1. create a Canvas element without rendering it,
2. assign a Chart.js chart to the canvas (I know how to do this) and, most importantly:
3. export the image data from canvas so I can forward the image data to PDFMake without ever displaying the canvas to the end-user. It has to happen in the background, inside the code.

Can extracting canvas data as an image be done without ever drawing the canvas element or even adding it to the DOM?

Comment: You can always position the canvas behind the main content container, or simply with absolute positioning with a large negative position. Of course it  does render, but not visibly to the user.

Comment: But is there any method to not place a canvas anywhere on the page but do the rendering/drawing only in the memory? I'm asking because of the possible performance hits, there might be hundreds of canvases added and removed.

Comment: Are you sure you even need to attach a canvas to the DOM in order to have it render things to its own memory? I don't think you need to put it in the DOM.

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do this  than adding the canvas to DOM and then grabbing the image data, that's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test, but ChartJS doesn't seem to be accepting an in-memory canvas created with `document.createElement('canvas')` so alternatively you can move your canvas off-screen so it's not visible.

Comment: Actually it does accept it, but it seems that chartjs uses the computedStyles to set-up the charts, and I didn't found any width or height parameters, so you'll only get a 0*0 canvas at the end. A simpler workaround IMO is to append the canvas before calling the `Chart` constructor and to remove it directly after : http://jsfiddle.net/t25j7xve/

Comment: @Kaiido. Yes, that's what my test showed -- an internal ChartJS error related to not finding the canvas element in the dom.

Comment: Ah, I was using verison 1.0.2, which didn't throw such an error. v2 does indeed.

Comment: I gave up on doing this and switched to server-side generated images because I need them in the PDF export. I'm sorry I didn't see this answer.
Anyway, this method would be overly complicated because there's `angular-chart` library in the middle of everything so it's simply not worth it :) Also, I switched to v2 so I guess it wouldn't work.